# How to set dynamic property binding in ngmodel angular4

Tags: angular

I am struck in making check list. I made a check list for dynamic data so i create html template in angular 4 like this

```
<div *ngFor="let Discipline of addDropDown.Disciplines let i = index">
          <div class="form-group clearfix" style="width:100%" *ngIf="i>=7">
            <label style="width: auto; float: left;margin-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 10px;">{{Discipline.Name}}</label>
            <div style="width: auto;float: right;margin:0 10px;">
              <label class="checkboxArea" style="width: auto;float: left;margin:0 10px;">
                <input [ngModel]="this['checkitem' + Discipline.Id]" (ngModelChange)="updateChecked($event,Discipline.Id)" type="checkbox">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I have problem in `[ngModel]="this['checkitem' + Discipline.Id]`

discipline id is different depends upon data and property value also change

sample data

```
{"173":false,"174":false,"175":false,"176":true,"177":false,"178":true,"179":true,"180":true,"181":false}
```

any other method to get property dynamically i also tried some methods it wont works..!!

tried methods are

```
[ngModel]="checkitem[Discipline.Id]" 
 [ngModel]="checkitem.[Discipline.Id]"
```

please give solution for that

Comment: have you tried : [ngModel]="'checkitem'{{Discipline.Id}}"

Comment: @Prithivi:[ngModel] is also right syntax

Comment: do you have any errors ?

Comment: @SandipPatel i try this angular4 is not allow this

Comment: @VivekDoshi  `checkitem` is object value and discipline.Id is present in `checkitem`

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO  i have no errors data `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got answer from long search

should use `[(ngModel)]="checkitem[Discipline.Id]"`

it works fine..thank you guys

Comment: How to display values after this.